# Getting particular index while using iterator

Tags: java, collections, iterator

I have a list in my code

```
List result = dm.findByCustomQuery(uc,query);
```

I want to get a certain value from the result particularly when the index is 0.

Is there a way i can use iterator and just get the value of list with index 0.

Comment: Why not just use `result.get(0)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you want use iterator to get the first element, anyway, this is how you can:

```
        Iterator<String> it = result.iterator();
        boolean first = true;

        while(it.hasNext()) {
            if (first) {
                System.out.println("The first element is: "+it.next() );
                first=false;
            } else {
                System.out.println("The next element is: "+it.next() );
            }
        }
```